building a Chrome extension| Can popup page be sandboxed page?
I'm trying to build with flutter simple chrome extension that connects to firebase and performing some crud. Google's CSP policy making my life hard by preventing me from loading scripts from external sources. In my case I don't need access to all chrome's apis.
Can I define that my popup page and sandbox page are the same page? And may google reject my app from extensions store?
I've tried to save all firebase script's locally, but it didn't worked despite not throwing any errors..

firebase has a ManifestV3-compatible bundle, more info. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.
